# SQL Report Builder V3: PDF pages are having margins which needs to be eliminate before creating

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, sqlreportingservice

[When we click on the print option, We got this dialog box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY89U.png)
[No margin settings for print to PDF option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo84c.png)
[Highlighted black area is the margin when we print the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T8h9.png)

I have 200K lines to print for a full batch report. For which I need to use the whole page with no margins to print. Can any body help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

In the report properties (right click outside the report design area) there are values for margin and paper size. Set paper size to custom and you can adjust the values manually, then check with print preview to see if it's close/adjust accordingly